# How do I set an attribute on an ODBC connection via DBExpress?

Tags: delphi, odbc, dbexpress

**Justification that you might as well skip reading but is included to filter out people telling me not to do something that I'm not sure of in the first place.**

I'm trying to debug some multithreaded database hoopla, it's mostly experimental although if I get it working I'd  be a very happy guy. I'm very new to DBExpress (only have been using it for 4-5 hours). I'm not using TSQLConnection or any designtime components because I'm trying to rewrite an existing ODBC32.dll interface in a painless an unnoticed way and once I'm done, I'll expose the rest of the awesomeness.  The reason I mention this is because it's very apparent that I'm not using dbexpress in the normal way shown in many of the tutorials.

---

**Here's the question**

I'm using the TDBXConnection and connecting to an ODBC datasource, I want to try setting the `SQL_ATTR_ASYNC_DBC_FUNCTIONS_ENABLE` parameter on my connection, but I don't have a clue where to go about setting that particular parameter.

Comment: Even though I think I figured out the answer to my question, I think we could all benefit from some wisdom if anyone else would like to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `FDBConnection : TDBXConnection;` defined somehwere else so now you've got to:

....

```
begin
  if FDBConnection is TDBXOdbcConnection then
  with FDBConnection as TDBXOdbcConnection do
  begin
    MethodTable.SQLSetEnvAttr(EnvironmentHandle, SQL_ASYNC_ENABLE, Pointer(SQL_ASYNC_ENABLE_ON), 0);
    MethodTable.SQLSetEnvAttr(EnvironmentHandle, SQL_ASYNC_DBC_FUNCTIONS, Pointer(SQL_ASYNC_DBC_CAPABLE), 0);

  end;
end;
```

That's pretty painless.

Include `Data.DBXODBC` and `System.ODBC` in the uses and you're golden.